# Python:what does "pix = im_pixel[j, i]" means?

Tags: python

I'm a newbie of python.

I couldn't understand the usage of `pix = im_pixel[j, i]`.

In `[]`, there is a comma (`,`).. Is this the right syntax?

Comment: Think `im_pixel[(j, i)]`, now does it make sense?

Comment: That makes sense. Why can we use this?

Answer (score 2):

`im_pixel[j,i]` just means that the key being passed to `im_pixel` is the tuple `j, i`. This will call whatever `im_pixel` has defined for `__getitem__` with this tuple as a parameter. What this does will be defined by the type of `im_pixel`

For example if `im_pixel` was a dictionary it would fetch the key `(j, i)`. Anything immutable and hashable is allowed to be a dictionary key in Python and a tuple is both immutable and hashable so this would be allowed for a dictionary type. As Duncan mentions the whole key must be immutable, so the individual elements of the tuple must also be immutable as well.

Comment: Pedantically a tuple is only immutable when all of the objects it contains are also immutable. So you can use a tuple of immutable objects as a dictionary key but you can't use a tuple that contains say a list or a dict.

Comment: @Duncan Pedantically (part 2), say hashable rather than immutable

Comment: There is no reason to believe that `im_pixel[j, i]` is a `dict` indexing operation, indeed, the names imply that `im_pixel` is a `numpy.ndarray`, in which case, accepts various things, including tuples, and slices. All you can really say is that `im_pixel[j, i]` is passing a tuple, `j, i` to the `__getitem__` method of the object referenced by `im_pixel`. There is no reason, in principle, why a type couldn't implement `__getitem__` to accept mutable types..

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes this is a good point, just assumed this was a dictionary when answering which as you point out is not necessarily correct.

Comment: @Chris_Rands yes just has to be hashable, but at least the properties used to calculate the hash had better be immutable otherwise bad things will happen if you mutate them.